# Vespa error container Container.com.yahoo.io.NativeIO warning native IO not possible failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted

Tags: vespa

I am new to Vespa and is seeing the following message. Is it due to some permission issue ? Vespa is running on Redhat linux 7.6

> container  Container.com.yahoo.io.NativeIO warning native IO not possible due to /tmp/jna-112098453/jna926736448349629269.tmp: /tmp/jna-112098453/jna926736448349629269.tmp: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted